# IE11 on my machine not playing H.264 video that works on other PCs

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-video, h.264

I have encoded videos as H.264 that aren't playing in IE11 on Windows *on my machine only*. They play just fine on other Windows 8 or 7 machines that I've been able to test on - and they play fine in Chrome/Firefox.

Yes I have the right MIME type.

It's definitely something wrong with my Internet Explorer because even the [canonical HTML5 video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) from w3schools fails on my Internet Explorer. However another MP4 video from HTML5VideoCreator works fine.

Here's a test page - for me only the Happy Fit [sic] video works in IE.

I just can't figure out what's different between these two encoded videos. Even if I use handbrake and re-encode the video as H.254 with 'web optimized' enabled it still won't play.

```html
<p>This works on my machine (Win 8 / IE 11)</p>

<video class="benefit-video" controls data-crossorigin="anonymous" preload="metadata" width="400" height="300">
    <source src="http://html5videocreator.github.io/data/images/happyfit2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<hr>

<p>This doesn't work on my machine (Win 8 / IE 11)</p>

<video class="benefit-video" controls data-crossorigin="anonymous" preload="metadata" width="400" height="300">
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Comment: have you tried resetting your IE settings?

Comment: @RomanCanlas I'm actually deliberately not trying to reset anything at this stage - or reboot. If NO H.264 video whatsoever was working I would have done that, but I'm getting certain videos loading while others aren't - so if this is my only chance to debug this then I wanted to be able to

Comment: Seems like I've got some other screwy things going on with my Internet Explorer - even after a reboot. My website uses fonts from fonts.com and they don't even display when I hit the site with https but every other machine they do. I use Fiddler with https 'interception' but I've got it disabled.